# How can i get unbanned from asking questions?

Tags: discussion, asking-questions

I got banned a while ago. How do I get back.

Answer (score 2):

Please refer to this meta post:

[What can I do when getting "We are no longer accepting questions/answers from this account"?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86997/)

The question posting ban is enforced automatically, and moderators are not able to lift this ban.